# Connection Pool Types in Astyanax Cassandra client

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax, netflix

From the past few weeks we were trying to evaluate different different `Cassandra clients` so now it looks like we will go forward with `Netflix/Astyanax client`.

We are trying to optimize `Cassandra database` mainly for `read performance`. Currently, I am creating `Astyanax connection` like this-

```
/**
 * Creating Cassandra connection using Astyanax client
 *
 */
private CassandraAstyanaxConnection() {

    context = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
    .forCluster(ModelConstants.CLUSTER)
    .forKeyspace(ModelConstants.KEYSPACE)
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()      
        .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.RING_DESCRIBE)
    )
    .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool")
        .setPort(9160)
        .setMaxConnsPerHost(40)
        .setSeeds("node1:9160,node2:9160,node3:9160,node4:9160")
    )
    .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()      
        .setCqlVersion("3.0.0")
        .setTargetCassandraVersion("1.2"))
    .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor())
    .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());

    context.start();
    keyspace = context.getEntity();

    emp_cf = ColumnFamily.newColumnFamily(
        ModelConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY, 
        StringSerializer.get(), 
        StringSerializer.get());
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

So by default, I believe `Astyanax client` will use `ConnectionPoolType as ROUND_ROBIN`.

Now I am trying to understand from the `read performance` point of view which one will be better from below options?

`TOKEN_AWARE or ROUND_ROBIN or BAG`

And what is the difference between those three? And how we decide that we should use one of them from above three?

Some background about our cluster. We are going to have single `cross colo cluster` with `24 nodes`. Meaning `12 nodes in SLC colo` and `12 nodes in PHX colo`.

And we are going to use `NetworkTopologyStrategy` with `replication factor of 4`, meaning `2 in each colo`. We will be using `LeveledCompactionStrategy`.

Any explanation on my above question will be of great help. There will be lot of people who will be using Astyanax client in the production environment. Any feedback will be of great help.

Thanks for the help.

**Update:-**

Still looking for an answer which can explain me what is the main difference between those three with an example so that I can understand better. I know what does those means in general but not able to understand form an example point of view how it will works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ROUND_ROBIN**

In this type of ConnectionPoolType, your connection will be instantiated in round robin type depending on the set of hosts.

**TOKEN_RANGE**

It is somewhat similar to ROUND_ROBIN type, sets up a basic token aware pool which will round robin all hosts within a token range

**BAG**

Don't know much about this type, but i guess it will something like, your connection will be instantiated from the BAG of hosts randomly, independent of token range or round robin pattern.

Comment: Thanks abhi. The things that you told me, I am already aware of it. I was trying to understand more in detail by looking a simple example how it will work out. I am mainly interested in the difference between ROUND_ROBIN vs TOKEN_AWARE Connection Pool Type and what is recommended to use for Read Performance?

Comment: hmmm... recommended will be TOKEN_WARE